# Does anyone have a Notepad++ plugin that will generate UUIDs and insert them

Tags: notepad++, uuid, autohotkey

I Often need UUIDs inserted into files that I'm editing in Notepad++.  Does anyone have a macro or add in that does this.  Or an autohotkey script?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Install the GhNppExec plugin from [Plugin Central](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php?title=Plugin_Central), then configure to run the simple Python script below.

Use the shortcut mapper to assign a key combination to the plugin command.

```
import uuid
import sys

# make a random UUID
sys.stdout.write(str(uuid.uuid4()).upper())
```

Comment: The Python Script plugin will do the job as well with the same code

Comment: I made a small adjustment to your script so it will replace your selected text: editor.replaceSel(str(uuid.uuid4()).upper())

Answer (score 14):

NppToolBucket does it very nicely, too.

http://sourceforge.net/p/npp-plugins/discussion/667712/thread/71f5e965

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, methinks! ... it properly does the job (but does need old .net framework installing)

Answer (score 2):

[(AHK) Universally Unique Identifier (UUID/GUID) Generator](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic14917.html)

It's not spectacular(has its flaws), but it looks to get the job done.