# Notepad++ - replace match with random number between range

Tags: notepad++

Need some help here please.

I have a textfile with database records like this:

> (350, 0, 'Text', 'Data'),
>
> (351, 0, 'Text', 'Data'),
>
> (352, 0, 'Text', 'Data'),

and so on.

What I want to do is I want to replace the '0' values in col2 with a random number between 1000 to 9999 (4 digits).

> (350, 1341, 'Text', 'Data'),
>
> (351, 1215, 'Text', 'Data'),
>
> (352, 1563, 'Text', 'Data'),

How do I best achieve this?

Comment: Why the `mysql` and the `SQL` tag?

Comment: Its a sql export / query.

Comment: But your question has nothing to do with SQL it can also be a string from other sources

Comment: You can't do that with Npp, you have to write a script in your favorite scripting language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use Code alignment plugin to align the fields
- Generate sufficient number of random numbers in Excel or using [a plugin for that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3234633/5690722) too on a separate tab
- Select random number values using Alt, Copy to clipboard
- Select '0' values to substitute on the target file tab using Alt
- Paste from clipboard